# How to fix image loading in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, file-upload

I'm trying to load a logo on Wordpress and it doesn't seem to work. Indeed, I added this function in my php file :

```php
function wp_theme_support(){
  add_theme_support('custom-logo');
}
```

Then I'm supposed to load it with the dashboard and this error appears (see error screenshot below). Please can someone help me ?[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDuXo.png)

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65538397/3821467 You need to add a mime type for SVG since it's not part of standard WP.

Answer (score 0):

svg is not supproted in upload, you should try uploading other formats or you can install and activate one of these plugins:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-svg/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/svg-support/

Comment: Thank you all for your answers ! It helped :D